# Activiti 7 with spring-boot 1.5.x support

Tags: spring-boot, activiti

I was creating spring-boot project with Activiti.

I noticed that Activiti option is now missing from https://start.spring.io/
for both 1.5.18 and 2.1.1 versions of spring boot.

The Activiti 7 is under development (beta available) with examples on spring-boot 2.x

Can I use Activiti 7 with spring-boot 1.5.18?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For spring boot 1.x you are probably safest [to use Activiti 6](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.activiti/activiti-spring-boot-starter-basic/6.0.0/jar) as Activiti 7 is being built for spring boot 2.x. But if you're especially interested in Activiti 7 then please feel free to ask on the [Activiti 7 gitter chat](https://gitter.im/Activiti/Activiti7) and discuss your use case with the development team and the community there.